# dhrystone results are same

Tags: unix, embedded, arm, embedded-linux

I am executing dhrystone 2.1 on freescale IMX6 quad processor with 1GHz.Below are the things I tried.
1. Executed dhrystone alone first time.
2. With an application running in the background, I executed dhrystone.
In either cases I am getting DMIPS value same. I do not understand. In second case DMIPS should reduce.Please let me know

Comment: **Quad core**; think about it.

Comment: You want to have even more fun, use different compiler settings, optimizations in particular, and notice what happens.

Comment: Do you mean to say dhrystone results in this context are not reliable? Please let me know. I am blocked totally on this

Comment: Can anyone comment on this. I am not getting any concrete result even on net

Answer (score 0):

You should think about why you expect the dhrystone benchmark to perform worse with another program running in the background. If you want them to fight for cpu time, you need to make sure they are bother scheduled on the same core, because if they are scheduled on different cores, they will each receive 100% cpu time. Another reason your could expect dhrystone to run slower with an app in the background would be shared cache collisions, or memory bandwidth. Both of these reason though I would disqualify for this discussion, because dhrystone is an extremely simple benchmark, which doesn't require much memory bandwidth or cache space. So your best way of slowing it down is scheduling the other app on the same core and restricting them both, so they can't be scheduled elsewhere. For more info on how to perform dhrystone benchmarking for arm refer to this document:

> http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0273a/DAI0273A_dhrystone_benchmarking.pdf

Comment: I agree. I also tried running both of them on a single core, by disabling other 3 cores. Even in this case result was same. As in when Dhrystone was run alone and second time Dhrystone and an application in the background was run. I got DMIPS as same .

Comment: Do you know in what order they were scheduled? And whether either of them interrupted each other during run time? What could have happened is that you background app was sleeping and the Dhrystone benchmark was running the whole time. That would explain the weird result.